On a graph, can a flow strictly dominate another one?
Consider a finite directed graph $\mathcal G=(\mathcal V,\mathcal E)$ and a set of simple paths $\mathcal P$ that all connect the same origin to the same destination. A flow on paths $f\in\Delta(\mathcal P)$ (i.e., a nonnegative vector whose components, labeled by $\mathcal P$, sum to $1$) induces a flow on edges $\mathcal E$ where, overloading the notation,
$$
f_e = \sum_{P\ni e} f_P.
$$
In the perspective of minimizing congestion, given two flows $f,g\in\Delta(\mathcal P)$ we say that $f$ dominates $g$ (denoted $f\preceq g$) if for all $e\in\mathcal E$, $f_e\leq g_e$, and $f$ strictly dominates $g$ (denoted $f\prec g$) if $f\preceq g$ and there exists an edge $e\in\mathcal E$ such that $f_e<g_e$.
Can there be two flows on paths $f,g\in\Delta(\mathcal P)$ such that $f\prec g$?
Of course, if the graph is made of parallel links, each path $P\in\mathcal P$ can be uniquely identified by an edge $e_P$ and thus as $f,g$ are probability distributions on $\mathcal P$, $f_e\leq g_e$ for all $e\in\mathcal E$ implies that $f=g$, hence no such flows exist for these graphs. The result extends to all graphs with that "unique identification property". The problem becomes more difficult, however, when considering non-trivial graph topologies.

Let $G$ be the graph with vertices $\{s, 1, 2, t\}$ and edges $\{s \to 1, s \to 2, 1 \to 2, 2 \to 1, 1 \to t, 2 \to t\}$. That is, start with a double edge $1 \leftrightarrow 2$, add arcs from $s$ to both $1$ and $2$, and add arcs from both $1$ and $2$ to $t$.
Let $$\mathcal P = \{s \to 1 \to t, s \to 2 \to t, s \to 1 \to 2 \to t, s \to 2 \to 1 \to t\}.$$
Then a flow with weight $\frac12$ on each of the first two paths is strictly dominated by a flow with weight $\frac12$ on each of the last two.
(If having edges between $1$ and $2$ in both directions is a problem, we can accomplish the same thing with a directed cycle on three or more vertices.)

Great solution. I actually have in mind a more specific class of flows $g$, which do not encompass the flow of this example, but this takes it for this formulation!
